# question on Natural Log, $\lim \limits_{n\to∞ }(1+\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2})^n $

Tags: limits, logarithms

I'm curious what is the solution of this. Is this just same as ordinary natural log?

$\lim \limits_{n\to∞ }(1+\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2})^n =e?$

A few people says the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ just goes to $'0'$, so it's same as  $'e'$.
But why? Why $\frac{1}{n}$ remains meaningful, while $\frac{1}{n^2}$ goes to zero??

I'm asking this because I'm stuck while deriving a formula.
I post the part of deriving as a picture. Look. From 1st, they go to 3rd line, by using 2nd. And I assume this suppose $\lim \limits_{n\to∞ }(1+\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2})^n $ is just same as 'e'.

Thank you genius[image]

Comment: get rid of the image. use Mathjax

Comment: More generally if $n(a_n-1)\to 0$ ie $a_n=1+o(1/n)$ then $a_n^n\to 1$. Now put $a_n=(1+n^{-1}+n^{-2})/(1+n^{-1})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: For any $\epsilon >0$ we have $1+\frac 1 n \leq 1+\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^{2}} \leq 1+\frac {1+\epsilon}  n$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Apply logarithm, multiply by $n$ and take the limit.

Comment: Indeed, the explicit relationship between $n$ and $\epsilon$ that makes the RHS inequality hold is $n \ge 1/\epsilon$.

Comment: I can't get it.. as what you said,
$\lim(1+\frac 1 n)^n \leq \lim(1+\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^{2}})^n \leq \lim(1+\frac {1+\epsilon}  n)^n$

$\lim(1+\frac {1+\epsilon}  n)^(frac\{1}{1+\epsilon} = e $

Comment: You get $e \leq \lim \inf (1+\frac 1  n+\frac 1 {n^{2}})^{n} \leq \lim \sup (1+\frac 1  n+\frac 1 {n^{2}})^{n}=e^{1+\epsilon}$. Now let $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Aha!  I got it thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $(1+\epsilon)^n\simeq 1+\epsilon n$ for $\epsilon\to 0$. If $\epsilon\sim O(1/n)$ then $\epsilon n \sim O(1)$ so such a term is relevant. If $\epsilon \sim O(1/n^2)$ then $\epsilon n\sim O(1/n)\to 0$.

Hence if you have $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ you have something in the form $(1+\epsilon_1 +\epsilon_2)^n$ with $\epsilon_1\sim O(1/n)$ and $\epsilon_2 \sim O(1/n^2)$. So you'll have $1+\epsilon_1 n + \epsilon_2 n$. The term in $\epsilon_1$ is of order $1$ (actually it's $e-1$) and the other is of order $1/n$ and becomes negligible.

To see things more rigorously you can take the log...
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n = e^{n\log(1+1/n+1/n^2)}=e^{(1+O(1/n)) +(1/n+O(1/n^2))}=e^{1+O(1/n)}\to e$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1+\frac{n+1}{n^2} \right)^{n}=\left(1+\frac{n+1}{n^2} \right)^{n \cdot\frac{n}{n+1} \cdot \frac{n+1}{n}}=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{y_n} \right)^{y_n}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow e $$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right) $$
so if $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to e$, then $\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)^n\to 1$ and $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n\to e$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n &=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}\\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} \\
&=e
\end{align}$$

Comment: $@$서영빈, can I know the reason for the downvote. Which part did you find it difficult to digest or what's wrong in the solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote! Thanks for answering

Comment: It's alright. My prime motive was that my answer should help you if not then I would have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

When $n>1$, we have
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n
<\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^n
=\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right).$$